# How to run git push command from Azure DevOps powershell task

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to run a PowerShell task in Azure DevOps.

I gave the script path in the PowerShell task. I have written execution of git commands in this script file. add & commit has been executed from the Azure portal, but not able to execute push command, the build frozen after committing.

Comment: Can you share the log? do you use Hosted agent or Private agent?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Are you running this on an agent under your control? It may be that Git is popping up an Autorization pop-up... You may need to disable the Git Credential Manager for Windows in your system. https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/issues/152

Comment: I agree with @hessehouwing, and maybe you can remotely log into the the server as the account executing the build agent ,IF it is a private build agent, and seeing if the commands execute successfully and prompt for credentials.  Whenever I have a build problem I always like to log into my build server as the build service account and resolve the issue that way.

Comment: @Shayki: I am using Private agent, for logfile [click here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FzGtnqp5m4UQpmvFO-t-kxaalZBO_QUS/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @jessehouwing: I disabled gcm in my server, still getting same problem

Comment: I get an error saying the logfile doesn't exist on Google Drive.

Comment: please click this [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1I8sNuQwuDYt2N8A_undJorPN-QyulPVl) for log file

Answer (score 1):

I came across such problem recently while configuring git commands in Azure DevOPs.
This is how I am able to git push

```
"Config Set"
git config user.email "$(Build.RequestedForEmail)"
git config  user.name "$(Build.RequestedFor)"
"Push new Branch"
git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer $(System.AccessToken)" push origin master:refs/heads/my-branch
```

Hope this helps someone else.